# JiraRestClient set assignee

Tags: jira, jira-rest-java-api

My shop is currently running Jira 5X, and I am attempting to use the Jira Rest Client to retrieve / progress issues.

I need to set values such as Assignee. Can anyone provide a good example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
IssueInput issueInput = IssueInput.createWithFields(new FieldInput(IssueFieldId.ASSIGNEE_FIELD, ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("name",
                    <username>)));
jiraRestClient.getIssueClient().updateIssue(<jiraKey>, issueInput).claim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the JavaDoc for the Java Jira Rest Client, it looks like it only supports update of a very limited set of issue attributes, and updatng the assignee is not supported - see the [methods for the IssueRestClient interface.](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira-rest-java-client/0.4/apidocs/com/atlassian/jira/rest/client/IssueRestClient.html)

You'd be best off contacting the project maintainers - the Java client is only in Alpha so they are probably adding new functionality to it regularly.

Comment: Gareth,

Thanks for responding.  I am using the Java Jira Rest Client.  com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.JiraRestClient.  I have heard that it doesn't have all the CRUD functionality yet.  I am able progress issues and vote but that seems to be all I can update.  I need to update things like Assignee.  Do you know if that is available now or soon to be?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were using the Java client.  Updating my answer accordingly.